# CRSF with XSS Parses % in GET request as %25

Tags: javascript, html, xss, csrf

**NOTE:** I am in a cyber security class and we have been learning about CSRF and XSS. The site for our projects in the class are purposely vulnerable to crsf and xss. I have a malicious html page with the following form that is submitted onload. You can see the script is attempting to overwrite a cookie. The encoding uses %xx to encode ASCII characters.

[image: Request with % encoding]

When I visit the malicious site, and then use the network monitoring in Chrome, I see the encoding for % has turned into %25.
[image]

I know that %25 in ASCII is just the percent symbol itself, but this encoding messes up the XSS. If I use the malicious XSS link outside of the CSRF html form, then the attack works and the cookie is overwritten. However, the encoding through the CSRF does not work to overwrite the cookie because the literal "%25" messes up the XSS script. Any tips on how to accomplish the XSS in the CSRF with this GET request? I am going to try other tools to perform the GET request through HTML and Javascript. I am an embedded programmer, so HTML and Javascript are not my forte, but I also have been looking online for ways around this and haven't understood why the change from % to %25 happens in the CSRF. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When setting the value attribute of the hidden form field in your HTML document, you should not URL encode. Instead you should encode characters that have special meaning in HTML as HTML entities:

- `<` becomes `&lt;`
- `"` becomes `&quot;`
- `&` becomes `&amp;`

Etc.